# EXT.Ajax.request going to success when JSON returns "success" : false

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have this EXT JS code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url     : "xxx",
                method  : "POST",
                params  : params,
                success : function(response) {
                            success();

                },
                failure : function(){
                            fail();
                }
        });
```

The url `xxx` returns this piece of JSON.

```
{"success": false }
```

For some reason this never goes into failure. It never runs the `fail()` method, always `success()`. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would call failure handler only when request would failed on the network level - if you get server error or server won't return anything. Otherwise it will be success and you need to parse response to see if it was logical failure.

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much for that. Now I understand. I figured it out now and fixed my code. Thanks again for a very informative answer.